# Adding a variable in curl command in a bash script

Tags: bash, api, rest, curl

I have a REST API call which uses a session ID as a header. The script below works fine.

```bash
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "SessionId":"abcdef123" https://example.com/a/b=1
```

I want to substitute the value for SessionId. I will be getting the value for SessionId variable from another script's output and will grep just the SessionId's value. Like below.

```bash
SessionId=`grep -o '"iSessionId": *"[^"]*' /tmp/b.txt | grep -o '[^"]*$'`
```

I tried various solutions, but I get the same error message given below.

```xml
<error><code>AUTH_01</code><description>Authentication failure. </description><statusCode>401</statusCode></error>
```

Any suggestions? TIA

Comment: `/tmp/b.txt` seems to be a JSON; can you post a sample of it containing the line of interest?

Comment: Hard to say without more information. Try putting `set -x` before the problem section to get an execution trace as it runs. Note: if the trace shows single-quotes around an argument, that just indicates it has some shell-syntax character(s) in it.

Comment: As the [bash tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) you used in your question instructs you to do - copy/paste your shell script(s) into https://shellcheck.net and fix the problems that tool tells you about before posting here if you still have a problem afterwards.

Comment: @EdMorton, you were right! I was using legacy backticks in my script. It works perfectly fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @Fravadona Thanks for your input! The substitution I made was SessionId: ${sessionId//[$'\t\r\n ']}" after running my script through ShellCheck. Thank you! :)